# Get Unix socket path of socket, which created one socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix-socket

I need to check if some file description under /proc/%pid/fd/%n points to socket, which was created by (for example) /run/user/%n/my_socket . I try to open an socket with O_PATH, but open returns (in some cases) fd above -1 and (in other) -1. Also, when passing good fd (above 0), getsockname also fails.

This is my code:

```
int sock = -1;
 
if (S_ISSOCK(stat_.st_mode)) {
  
  sock = open(path,  O_PATH);
}

if (-1 != sock) {
  if (-1 == getsockname(sock, socket_, &len)) {
  
    if (errno == EBADF) {
    
      puts("BAD FD");
      return false;
    }
    perror("Error while obtaining data about socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  else puts("OKI - this is socket");
  
  if (socket_->sa_family == AF_UNIX)
    puts(socket_->sa_data);
}
```

Important info: I known, that when server creates an socket, it was created for listen for new connections only. When client connects, new socket was created to talk with it. So my question is: how to get prior socket from socket born from prior socket .

Comment: I known, that when server creates an socket, it was created for listen for new connections only. When client connects, new socket was created to talk with it. So my question is: how to get prior socket from socket born from prior socket.

Comment: Put clarifications in the question with the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68304317/edit) link, not comments.

Comment: Unix-domain sockets don't have differerent names when you connect them. There's nothing analogous to local and remote port numbers like in TCP.

Comment: Ok. I do stat on files in /proc/%n/fd/ and there is no path to my unix domain socket. I also search it in maps file under /proc/%n. Nothing important for me. How to get path of named socket from information under /proc/%d?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. I don't think you can use `open()` with a Unix-domain socket. You have to use `connect()` or `bind()`.

Comment: Correctly, but I need to test if program open some socket to connect to other program. I will wrote, what I try to achieve. I try to create some small applications, which indeed to run another programs. It test program is console or GUI or other app. Currently, I test if program is console application. I try to check it is GUI app by checking it connects to wayland or X socket. I can also read library it load, but it worst solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I found an solution.

Use readlink for symbolic links inside /proc/%n/fd . If it have special format, we can parse it as number of unix socket. In next step read whole /proc/net/unix file and search for number obtained from symbolic link. If found, check path. Now, I must search method to parse symbolic link and /proc/net/unix file.